# How to create a Swift method to use evaluateJavaScript with GCD

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch, evaluatejavascript

How do I create a macOS method that takes a URL parameter and returns HTML using evaluateJavaScript?

I want to scrape a URL that uses JavaScript, so neither String(contentsOf: url) nor URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) seem to work.

The code below works, but it creates a global, rather than returning a String.  I want code I can reuse in other similar projects.

Can I use didSet{} or GCD DispatchGroup() and group.enter() and group.leave() to create either a class or ViewController extension to create a simple method that returns only when the page loads and the JavaScript completes?  I assume I'll need a class to catch the WKNavigationDelegate calls.

I want a macOS method, not an iOS method.

Here is my working code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
var webView: WKWebView!
var  webString: String = "" {
    didSet {
        print("webString: \(webString.count) Bytes")
        print("\(webString)")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.someWebsite.com")!
    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(myRequest)
}

// WKNavigationDelegate methods
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish: WKNavigation!) {
    print(#function)

    webView.evaluateJavaScript(
        "document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()",
        completionHandler: { (html: Any?, error: Error?) in
            self.webString = html as! String
            print("In compHandler, HTML: \(self.webString.count) bytes\n")
    })
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail: WKNavigation!, withError: Error) {
    print(#function)
    print("ERROR: Error=\(withError)")
}
```

I want something similar to this code that I use for synchronous dowloads:

```
func downloadDataTask(url: String) -> String {
var returnStr = ""

guard let myURL = URL(string: url) else {
    showErrorAlert(
        title: "ERROR: Invalid URL",
        message: "Invalid URL in downloadDataTask()\n  URL:'\(url)'")
    return("Error: Invalid URL: '\(url)'")
}

let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myURL) { data, urlResponse, error in

    if let myData = data {
        let string = String(decoding: myData, as: UTF8.self)
        returnStr = string

        group.leave()
    } else {
        showErrorAlert(
            title: "ERROR: Unable to load HTML from URL",
            message: "Unable to load HTML in downloadDataTask()\n")
        group.leave()
    }
}
task.resume()

// wait for async completion handler task to complete
group.wait()

return(returnStr)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your question seems to actually be about getting results from an asynchronous process. Typically you'd do that by accepting a completion handler, and calling that in the `evaluateJavaScript` completion handler. Is that what you're looking for? You should not try to turn this into a synchronous function (a function you call and just get a result back). That will create a deadlock since WebViews require the main queue.

Comment: WRob Yes, I'm looking for a synchronous task that will block until the URLRequest webview load and evaluateJavaScript completion handler finish, then return the string from the JS completion handler.  I know this will block the main thread.  I am creating a "quick and dirty" method for my own personal use.  This will never go in an App Store app.  I currently have a similar simple method for shared URLSession download task, but don't know how to handle async for the evaluateJavaScript, since it can return an error via webView( didFail: ).  How would I do this?

Comment: Don't, not even quick and dirty. This won't just delay the main queue. This will deadlock because it will need to reenter the main queue to process the WebKit events. Use a completion handler.

Comment: ... I am also open to learning how to do this the right way, but I rally do want to start off with a simple synchronous method...

Comment: There is no simple synchronous method. You would have to kick this off on a non-main queue, and block there, so that the background queue would wait on the main queue. That's way more complicated. This isn't about blocking. It's about reentrant deadlocking.

Comment: Now what you might explore is JavaScriptCore, which would allow you to avoid WebKit and so you could manage your own queues. But it's likely much more complicated because you'll probably need to parse the JavaScript out of the HTML yourself. I don't know of a way to handle HTML to a JSContext for evaluation.

Comment: Alternately, since this is a Mac app, you could spawn a separate XPC process for evaluating the HTML that has its own main queue, and block on *that*. But again, way more complicated than a completion handler.

Comment: I added the sync download task, as an example of what I think is a "simple" sync method.  Again, I understand this is not how Apple recommends performing a download. Can you help me understand how to create a class and use this simple blocking mechanism?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't. WebKit requires various things to run on the main queue. URLSession does not. That's the difference. This isn't about "recommendations." This is about deadlocks. You can't block a queue while waiting for something must run on that same queue. It's not a matter of best practice. It's the definition of a deadlock.

Comment: Check the docs for `evaluateJavaScript(...)`. "The completion handler always runs on the main thread." How is that going to run if you've blocked the main thread waiting for this process to complete?

Comment: OK.  I didn't know webKit runs on the main thread. Thank you for teaching me. My knowledge of threads, and processes comes from C and UNIX. I am still a beginner with Apples frameworks.  Are you saying there is no simple way for 2 task on the main thread to communicate?  No polling or semaphores? For my use case, getting the HTML is the starting point.  I don't have a simple "updateUI()" I can add to the completion handler. I'm really not trying to be stubborn here, just trying to understand my choices.  Any direction you can provide would be appreciated.  Thanks again!

Comment: A task cannot block a thread, and wait on something that also runs on that thread. That is a basic fact of threads. It has nothing to do with Apple's frameworks. The standard solution to this in most systems is continuation passing (i.e. completion handlers). "Do this, and when it completes, do this." That has nothing to do with UI. It's exactly how you'd write this in Node.js, for example. If you're working in macOS 10.15 or later, you can also use Combine and write it in a reactive stye. But it's still ultimately "do this, and when it finishes, do this." You can't block.